# Paypal recurring payment but not monthly

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring

I want to build a website where the buyer subscribes to my product, that's not monthy but quarterly. I have two questions:

- Is it possible to set up a quarterly payment, so that the user subscribes but gets charged every three months?
- Is it possible to set up a 'pay per thing' payment, so that the user accepts the subscription but is only charged when I, the seller, push a button or similar.

For the latter one, an example: Let's say I publish every three months. I published, I click "charge!" and it charges my subscribers. Three months go by and I can't publish yet, so I won't click "charge!" until next month.

Are those questions answerable? Are them possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Paypal's Enhanced Recurring Payments with Automatic Billing to achieve this.

For your first scenario you would just use the subscription service

For your second scenario you would use automatic billing.

Keep in mind there are legal requirements for both that will vary based on your locality. For example, in the US a subscription is a form of contract and you could not offer "Subscriptions" to a product that might not be regularly delivered (unless you built int a grace period into your subscription contract, in which case, you would be allowed to charge the person even if the delivery was late)

Comment: Is there documentation for these features?